# Changing TextView dynamically with time in Android

Tags: android-activity, textview, android-2.2-froyo

I am a beginner in android. I want to change my text view with time.
My activity lasts for 5 seconds and i want to display the count down time.
I tried using Thread timer,but it doesnt work.
 Simply i want to show the numbers like

In the Beginning:  5, 
After a second:  4, 
After 2 seconds: 3, 
     ,,        : 2,
     ,,        : 1,

Please suggest me how to code this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CountDownTimer:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCount);

    final int secs = 5;
    new CountDownTimer((secs +1) * 1000, 1000) // Wait 5 secs, tick every 1 sec
    {
        @Override
        public final void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            txtCount.setText("" + (int) (millisUntilFinished * .001f));
        }
        @Override
        public final void onFinish()
        {
            txtCount.setText("GO!");
        }
    }.start();
}
```